# Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: kg.aladin.jdbc.Student.books[kg.aladin.jdbc.Book]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having problems with one to many relationship I was surfing from web and could not fix. I double check @Entity declarations they were referring to `import javax.persistence.Entity;` before that I tried unidirectional only ManyToOne and it was working

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Book.class, mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

public Student() {

}
 // accessors ...
}
```

and Book object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
private Student student;

public Book() {
}
  //// accessors
}
```

[image]

and here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

```
<session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/***?useSSL=false</property>
    <property name="connection.username">***</property>
    <property name="connection.password">***</property>


    <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>


    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>


    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Entities have to be registered. You can do it in your xml-File:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<session-factory>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/***?useSSL=false</property>
    <property name="connection.username">***</property>
    <property name="connection.password">***</property>


    <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>


    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>


    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Register Classes -->
    <mapping class="kg.aladin.jdbc.Student"/>
    <mapping class="kg.aladin.jdbc.Book"/>

    <!-- Or Register Packages -->
    <mapping package="kg.aladin.jdbc"/>

</session-factory>
```

See also: 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/ch01.html
and
[Hibernate problem - "Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956855/hibernate-problem-use-of-onetomany-or-manytomany-targeting-an-unmapped-clas?rq=1)

I hope it helps :-)